# Dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04) boots straight into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, 19.04

I recently re-installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04 indual boot (curiously, the issue I am about to describe was not present before). When I boot my laptop it goes straight into windows rather than the menu where I can decide between Ubuntu, Windows  (the one with purple background).
I tried to fix this with:

- `grub customizer`
- in the UEFI settings
- with `efibootmgr` (running from an ubuntu live USB drive, [as described here](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-uefi-bootloader-issues-when-dual-booting-2200655))
- with `boot-repair` (which produced [this report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MNt6nyVvfH/))

Nothing solved the issue. Any ideas?

p.s: my laptop in a Dell Chromebook 13 (aka LULU) with full UEFI firmware by [MrChromebox](https://mrchromebox.tech/#home)

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me dual booting.
try hitting escape key while booting until you get the boot options menu.
there should be an F9 option to pick the uefi mode.if you installed correctly
ubunu efi boot should be present.from there ubuntu should start.
or F10 bios setup go to boot manager ther should be 2 options windows and ubuntu.
pick ubuntu,and you will boot into grub menu every time.
this is common when installing windows after linux.