# Laptop booting straight into Windows after Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot

Title, scoured Google, asked the Odin Project Tech Support and Ask Ubuntu and didn't get a response, questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223611/computer-boots-straight-into-windows-dual-boot) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169396/dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-19-04-boots-straight-into-windows) didn't help, totally at my wits end. There's so much info out there I don't even know what's relevant/helpful information, but here's the gist - I followed the instructions [here](https://medium.com/linuxforeveryone/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-and-dual-boot-alongside-windows-10-323a85271a73), from "Installing Ubuntu" down.

It was a nightmare to get it to recognize my free partition on my one and only drive (SSD), but it finally did, I got an "Installation Complete", and then it said I needed to restart to use Ubuntu. I did, and it went straight to Windows. Not only that, but in the BIOS config screen there's no option for Ubuntu at all. It's just like it doesn't exist. I even put my bootable USB back in to access the GRUB (only way I could figure out how to access GRUB, instructions I followed online to hold down Shift while starting up didn't work), and there's not on-disk Ubuntu option there either.

Fast boot is disabled, secure boot is enabled.

Any help is **HUGELY** appreciated, and I'll provide any information asked for if it's helpful, I just didn't want to overload here with irrelevant stuff.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What brand/model system? Some like Acer require special settings. Some like many HP need boot order changed in UEFI settings. You did install in UEFI boot mode? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred I appreciate the response - I actually just found out a couple hours ago that all the issues I'm having is due to Intel Optane Boot Manager.

Comment: My new Dell just worked with 22.04. It implemented the Intel® VMD driver which has been in kernel for a while, but I do not think Ubuntu used it until 22.04. So my RAID on system just booted. I forgot to check settings before installing & it just worked. It shows: Kernel modules: vmd, ahci and vmd in use.